# Xcode 6 UIView set width to zero causes height equals zero as well

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, xcode6, cgrect

I have next code below:

```
- (IBAction)onTappedAddValue:(id)sender
{
    CGRect rect = self.progressView.frame;

    rect.size.width = rect.size.width + 1;

    self.progressView.frame = rect;

    NSLog(@"%@", [NSValue valueWithCGRect:self.progressView.frame]);
}
```

by pressing on the button I resize my view, so everything works good if view has for example rect (0, 0, 100, 10);

but if I set width to the 0 in storyboard and heigh to 10 points, by some reason SDK thinks that height also should equal 0 after pressing button and invocation code above.

Please check this [video](http://youtu.be/9nRLh4Fgbec) and [sources](https://github.com/matrosovDev/Xcode6IncrementWidthIssue) if you want to see how it works. When I set UIView's width to zero in storyboard and then try to increment it by pressing button, the width is incrementing but by some reason height is equal to zero but in stroryboard it has 10 pt.

Comment: Does a shape without an area even exist? *Mind-blown*

Comment: What do you mean? You can download code. there is only one view where I change frame on runtime. When view has width = 10, height = 10 that's ok, but if you change with = 0, height = 0, then by some reason sdk thinks that height also should be 0 as well. But I am not sure why?

Comment: It kind of makes sense if you think about it from a geometric point of view. If you reduce the width or height of a rectangle to zero then it's not really a rectangle anymore.

Comment: @CrimsonChris, really? omg, but what should I do? every time set height and width?

Comment: @CrimsonChris, seems I got idea, about how sdk works, but I thought about 0 as about an point or value not as a shape, as like some property. In any case then storyboard should avoid this I think if you set height or width to 0 it automatically should change it to 0 for both I think?

Comment: Setting the height in the code is probably the simplest thing...

Comment: Have you tried setting the width in the storyboard to 0.01?

Comment: @CrimsonChris unfortunately, this is not possible, ok any case I understand the issue. but just though that the 0 does not affect on a height.